# Symbolic linkage or in-sync folder replication on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, sync, symbolic-link, replication

I have an application—actually a web-framework+web-server—which requires its folders—including the application I'm hosting—to be in  a child directory; e.g., in: `\htdocs`.

The application/project I'm hosting is part of a bigger git repository, thus also cannot be moved outside of a child directory.

**On Windows, is it possible to do some sort of symbolic linkage or in-sync folder replication?**

I.e.: so when I update the contents of the folder it is also updated in its sister location.

Comment: Might help to state what version of windows - newer ones have much better symlink support.

Comment: I believe the command you might be looking for is mklink which is available in vista and above. Otherwise you will most likely need to use the junction program from sysinternal. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768

Comment: Windows 8. I've been looking through the `mklink` and `junction` commands, both are giving me: "Error creating foo:
Cannot create a file when that file already exists." errors. `E:>mkdir a && echo fff > a\bar.txt && junction a foo` and `E:>mkdir a && echo fff > a\bar.txt && mkdir foo && junction a foo` both gave this error.

Comment: You can also use http://allwaysync.com/ which can monitor a folder and sync it to another either one way syncing or bi directional.

Comment: Try this command "md a && echo fff > a\bar.txt && mklink /J foo a" a is the real folder and foo is the junction that points to a.